# Qooxdoo: Include tree into a form

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I'm trying to include the tree widget into a form with the qooxdoo form controller. Please check the code in this [playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520form%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Form()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520tree%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tree.Tree().set(%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520width%2520%253A%2520200%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520data%2520%253D%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509'id'%2520%253A%2520'1'%252C%250D%250A%2509'parent_id'%2520%253A%2520'null'%252C%250D%250A%2509'title'%2520%253A%2520'Root'%252C%250D%250A%2509'children'%2520%253A%2520%255B%250D%250A%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509'id'%2520%253A%2520'2'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'parent_id'%2520%253A%2520'1'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'title'%2520%253A%2520'Node%25201'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'children'%2520%253A%2520%255B%255D%250D%250A%2509%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509'id'%2520%253A%2520'3'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'parent_id'%2520%253A%2520'1'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'title'%2520%253A%2520'Node%25202'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'children'%2520%253A%2520%255B%255D%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%255D%250D%250A%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%252F%252F%2520tree%2520model%2520and%2520controller%250D%250Avar%2520model%2520%253D%2520qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(data)%253B%250D%250Avar%2520controller%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.controller.Tree(model%252C%2520tree%252C%2520%2522children%2522%252C%2520%2522title%2522)%253B%250D%250Atree.getRoot().setOpen(true)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Aform.add(tree%252C%2520'Tree'%252C%2520null%252C%2520'id')%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%252F%252F%2520form%2520controller%250D%250Avar%2520formController%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.controller.Form(null%252C%2520form)%253B%250D%250AformController.createModel()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520sendButton%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Send%2522)%253B%250D%250AsendButton.setWidth(70)%253B%250D%250Aform.addButton(sendButton)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250AsendButton.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509if%2520(form.validate())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509alert(%2522You%2520are%2520saving%253A%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520qx.util.Serializer.toJson(formController.getModel()))%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Athis.getRoot().add(new%2520qx.ui.form.renderer.Single(form))%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D).

What I want to achieve is that on click on the Send-button only the id (or another property of the currently selected node in the tree) is being sent and not the whole model data (including all of its children) of the selected node.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520form%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Form()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520tree%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.tree.Tree().set(%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520width%2520%253A%2520200%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520data%2520%253D%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509'id'%2520%253A%2520'1'%252C%250D%250A%2509'parent_id'%2520%253A%2520'null'%252C%250D%250A%2509'title'%2520%253A%2520'Root'%252C%250D%250A%2509'children'%2520%253A%2520%255B%250D%250A%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509'id'%2520%253A%2520'2'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'parent_id'%2520%253A%2520'1'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'title'%2520%253A%2520'Node%25201'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'children'%2520%253A%2520%255B%255D%250D%250A%2509%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509'id'%2520%253A%2520'3'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'parent_id'%2520%253A%2520'1'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'title'%2520%253A%2520'Node%25202'%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509'children'%2520%253A%2520%255B%255D%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%255D%250D%250A%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%252F%252F%2520tree%2520model%2520and%2520controller%250D%250Avar%2520model%2520%253D%2520qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(data)%253B%250D%250Avar%2520controller%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.controller.Tree(model%252C%2520tree%252C%2520%2522children%2522%252C%2520%2522title%2522)%253B%250D%250Atree.getRoot().setOpen(true)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Aform.add(tree%252C%2520'Tree'%252C%2520null%252C%2520'id')%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%252F%252F%2520form%2520controller%250D%250Avar%2520formController%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.controller.Form(null%252C%2520form)%253B%250D%250AformController.createModel()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520sendButton%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Send%2522)%253B%250D%250AsendButton.setWidth(70)%253B%250D%250Aform.addButton(sendButton)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250AsendButton.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509if%2520(form.validate())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509alert(%2522You%2520are%2520saving%253A%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520qx.util.Serializer.toJson(formController.getModel().getId().getId()))%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Athis.getRoot().add(new%2520qx.ui.form.renderer.Single(form))%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D) is a small update of your playground example to get only the ID of the selected node using :

```
formController.getModel().getId().getId()
```

Comment: Yes, I've found the same solution on my own. Just thinking too complicated. Anyway, thanks for your answer.